# Can you enable 2FA for git commits?

Tags: git, security, ubuntu, authentication

Title pretty much says it all. I'm using Ubuntu and I'm very paranoid about having my git repositories tampered with, so I want to make sure I'm the only one who can make commits. I know you can sign your commits locally, but if there was malware on your computer then it could get your private keys easily (I think). So I'd like to make it so for every local commit, git requires 2FA. Is there any way to accomplish this? Or is there some other more-secure alternative to local signing?

Comment: Commits are made locally. Do you mean pushing or pulling?

Comment: no I mean I want to require 2FA locally. I know it's weird, but the reason is that I'm not 100% sure my computer is malware-free, so I want to know every step of the way that I'm the only one making commits. Because if there _is_ malware on my machine, it could find any private keys I use to sign locally, which would make them useless, and make my commit history untrustworthy.

Comment: You don’t trust your own machine?

Comment: no, not really. It's kind of old and over the course of owning it I've clicked risky links. It's probably safe-ish, but I just want to make sure I'm not publishing code that's been tampered with.

Comment: 2FA doesn't help either because if there is malware on your smartphone then it could steal the 2nd factor too.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I trust my phone more than my computer. Plus, they still couldn't do anything unless they had my pass _and_ my phone. Theoretically, if the same malware was on both my computer and my phone, then it could pull that off, but I think it's unlikely.

Comment: "You like your phone better than me, don't you Dave ?" I do not dare think about how your quest will end ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't offer 2FA on the local machine because the user is implicitly trusted to create commits in their own repository.  However, you can sign all commits with a digital OpenPGP signature if you set `commit.gpgsign` to `true`.

You can use an OpenPGP key that is on a device such as a YubiKey that requires interaction before it can be signed.  [YubiCo's website](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000006420-using-your-yubikey-with-openpgp) documents how to do this.

*However*, having said that, if you don't trust your own computer, you're going to have a difficult time doing anything on it because everything you do would have to be verified on another, trustworthy machine, since malware on your own machine could trick you into seeing that things were different than they were.  So if that's your problem, you'll need to address it first before trying to add commit signing.  You could boot off a trusted live CD or live USB image (e.g., a Debian Live CD) to do certain work if need be.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the thing you want to have is named "code signing". You don't achieve it with 2FA, as 2FA is meant for authentication only. Imagine following:

1. For the whole code base you are going to commit you generate a SHA256 digest of all files.
2. You sign the digest with your key held somewhere else.
3. You store it in another file and add to the commit.
4. Later you may verify that the code base is what you expect it to be.

This will not prevent "reply attacks", but I believe this should fulfil your requirements.

I don't know any tools that could help you achieve this, but if you don't need to share the key with others to verify the integrity too, you may stick to a simple HMAC with a symmetric key.

Comment: So you store your keys somewhere other than your computer? Most of the stuff I've read about code signing has you generate keys in your terminal and store them in some directory on the same machine you're using for development. But what I'm concerned about is that my computer could be insecure, and if there were malware on it then my keys wouldn't be safe, right?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of exercise : you could review (and sign ?) the commits from a trusted device

- push your commits to a shared server (GitHub ?)
- from another trusted device : fetch them and review them
- do something to mark the reviewed commits as trusted :

  - push them to a repo on which the compromised computer has no write access
  - or tag them with a signed tag that confirms the commits content (you would need to prevent the account used on the compromised computer from tampering with these tags, to avoid deleting them or turning them into invalid signatures)